# Calculating a value for current week and rolling that value for subsequent weeks

Tags: mysql

I have the following 2 datasets:

Dataset A

```
Item  Location   Date                  X    Y 
 A      USA     Sep 10(Current Week)  10   10 
 A      USA     Sep 17                15   20          
 A      USA     Sep 24                10    5 
 A     Canada   Sep 10(Current Week)   0    4
 A     Canada   Sep 17                 6    0
 A     Canada   Sep 24                 13   15
 B      USA     Sep 10(Current Week)   10   50
 B      USA     Sep 17                 5    15
 B      USA     Sep 24                 15   20
```

Dataset B:

```
  Item    Location     Z
   A        USA        15
   A        Canada     0
   B         USA       25
```

I need an output dataset as follows:

O/P

```
   Item   Location   Date   Final_Column
    A      USA      Sep 10     15
    A      USA      Sep 17     20
    A      USA      Sep 24     15
    A    Canada     Sep 10      4
    A    Canada     Sep 17      0
    A    Canada     Sep 24      2
    B      USA      Sep 10      65
    B      USA      Sep 17      75
    B      USA      Sep 24      80
```

The calculation is as follows:

```
   For current week, Final Column = (Z - X) + Y ----> 1st week value

   For 2nd week, Final Column = (1st week value - X) + Y  ----> 2nd week value

   For 3rd week, Final Column = (2nd week value - X) + Y  ----> 3rd week value
```

and so on ...

```
 Additionally, if value of Final Column < 0 then Final Column = 0.
```

How to achieve this calculation in MySQL?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Not sure for the syntax.

```
select a.item, a.location, a.date,
@value = case when @item <> a.item or @location <> a.location then b.z - a.x + a.y
else
@value - a.x + a.y end final_column
from    a inner join b on a.item = b.item and a.location = b.location,
(select @value := 0, @item := '', @location := '') x
order by a.item, a.location, a.date
```

Below 0 will output as 0 :

```
select a.item, a.location, a.date,
@value = case when @item <> a.item or @location <> a.location then b.z - a.x + a.y
    else
    @value - a.x + a.y end temp_column,
@value = case when @value < 0 then 0 else @value end final_column
from    a inner join b on a.item = b.item and a.location = b.location,
(select @value := 0, @item := '', @location := '') x
order by a.item, a.location, a.date
```

Tell my if having a temp column is an issue.

Comment: Hi, this worked. But I need to be able to recode values that fall below 0 to 0.